# How gRPC and Kafka work together in microservice architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

I am new learner to microservice architecture. I am curious that most of people discuss how to choose either grpc(synchronization) or kafka(asynchronization) for communication between microservices but no topic talk about how make them to work together in the same microservice system. For the system of company I worked, as I know that each microservice are using grpc as request/response meanwhile kafka as messaging component. How they work behind the scene? How the payload of messaging looks like?

Answer (score 1):

They don't work together any differently than HTTP or Rsocket would work with Kafka; there's no overlap. One request comes in one way, gets forwarded to another client.

gRPC requires point to point communication between apps. Kafka requires external servers.

Both payloads are serialized as binary and would usually have some deserialization process internally to your app